# CRCase_RowSelecting fires with next case on subsequent save

Tags: c#, acumatica

I created an extension for `CRCaseMaint`, and added the event `CRCase_RowSelecting`.  Here is the code I am currently using:

```
    protected virtual void CRCase_RowSelecting(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        CRCase row = e.Row as CRCase;
        if (row == null) return;

        PXDatabase.ResetSlot<List<CRCase>>("OriginalCase");
        List<CRCase> originalCaseSlot = PXDatabase.GetSlot<List<CRCase>>("OriginalCase");

        if (originalCaseSlot.Count == 0)
        {
            originalCaseSlot.Add(sender.CreateCopy(row) as CRCase);
        }
        else
        {
            originalCaseSlot[0] = sender.CreateCopy(row) as CRCase;
        }
    }
```

When I first open a case, this event will fire a couple times, and the last time it fires, the current case is correctly stored in e.Row, so this code works great.  When I click Save, I have a `RowPersisting` event that compares the case stored in the  `originalCaseSlot` with the updated case.  At the end, it sets the original case slot to the updated case.  This also works well.

However, when I make another change without leaving the case, and click save, `e.Row` on the `RowSelecting` event now has the next case stored on it rather than the current case.  Since I am not touching the next case in any way, I am surprised that this is happening.

My question is, should I be using a different event instead of `RowSelecting`, or is there something else I am missing?

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: What is the goal of the code in RowSelecting? Maybe you could compare the rows in RowSelecting vs the view.current record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when the primary record gets updated or the user clicks on a form toolbar button, the framework selects 2 records from database: the current primary record and the next one. This is why `RowSelecting` is invoked 2nd time for the next **CRCase** record.

Honestly, using **PXDatabase Slots** to store user session-specific records is not a good idea. **PXDatabase Slots** are shared among all user sessions and should only be used to cache frequently used data from database, which is not prone to frequent updates. This makes the main purpose of **PXDatabase Slots** to reduce number of database queries to widely and very often used configurable data, like Segment Key or Attribute configurations.

With that said, using the `RowSelecting` handler is definitely a step in the right direction. Besides, the `RowSelecting` handler, you should additionally define a separate **PrevVersionCase** data view to store the original **CRCase** record(s) and also override the **Persist** method to report about changes. The **Locate** method used on **PXCache** objects searches the cache for a data record that has the same key fields as the provided data record. This approach allows to compare changes between the originally cached and modified **CRCase** records having identical key field values.

```
public class CRCaseMaintExt : PXGraphExtension<CRCaseMaint>
{
    [Serializable]
    public class CRPrevVersionCase : CRCase
    { }

    public PXSelect<CRPrevVersionCase> PrevVersionCase;

    protected virtual void CRCase_RowSelecting(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        CRCase row = e.Row as CRCase;
        if (row == null || e.IsReadOnly) return;

        var versionCase = new CRPrevVersionCase();
        var versionCache = PrevVersionCase.Cache;
        sender.RestoreCopy(versionCase, row);
        if (versionCache.Locate(versionCase) == null)
        {
            versionCache.SetStatus(versionCase, PXEntryStatus.Held);
        }
    }

    [PXOverride]
    public void Persist(Action del)
    {
        var origCase = Base.Case.Current;
        var origCache = Base.Case.Cache;
        CRPrevVersionCase versionCase;

        if (origCache.GetStatus(origCase) == PXEntryStatus.Updated)
        {
            versionCase = new CRPrevVersionCase();
            origCache.RestoreCopy(versionCase, origCase);
            versionCase = PrevVersionCase.Cache.Locate(versionCase) as CRPrevVersionCase;

            if (versionCase != null)
            {
                foreach (var field in Base.Case.Cache.Fields)
                {
                    if (!Base.Case.Cache.FieldValueEqual(origCase, versionCase, field))
                    {
                        PXTrace.WriteInformation(string.Format(
                            "Field {0} was updated", field));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        del();

        if (origCase != null)
        {
            PrevVersionCase.Cache.Clear();
            versionCase = new CRPrevVersionCase();
            Base.Case.Cache.RestoreCopy(versionCase, origCase);
            PrevVersionCase.Cache.SetStatus(versionCase, PXEntryStatus.Held);
        }
    }
}

public static class PXCacheExtMethods
{
    public static bool FieldValueEqual(this PXCache cache, 
        object a, object b, string fieldName)
    {
        return Equals(cache.GetValue(a, fieldName), cache.GetValue(b, fieldName));
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for helping us out with this Ruslan!  I really appreciate the time put in to provide this to myself and others looking to do something similar.  I had a feeling the database slots were shared across the instance.  Thank you for verifying that for me.

Comment: You're very welcome, @JoeS! Could you please accept the answer by clicking on the check button on the left side?